# How to mount a ebs_block_device using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Could anyone advise on how I can auto-mount an EBS volume created using Terraform and make it available on `/custom`?

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec201" {
...
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sdd"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 10
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = true
  }
...
```

Is it possible to auto-mount it?

I've read these pages:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html
- [Automatically mount an EBS volume upon starting an Amazon EC2 Linux instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006805/automatically-mount-an-ebs-volume-upon-starting-an-amazon-ec2-linux-instance)

When I do a:

```
> lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme1n1     259:0    0   10G  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:1    0  250G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  250G  0 part /
```

I have a 10GB partition that is not mounted. Would it be possible to auto-mount it using terraform?

Comment: You will need to run a [`remote-exec` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html) that connects to the instance and runs a command to mount it or have userdata automatically mount it on first boot.

Comment: Yes. Ok but do you have any clue how? Because, I don't see /dev/sdd in the instance once created. So 'im confused :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can to see, your SO reads `nvme1n1` as name of device (not `/dev/sdd`).

So, you could apply an `user_data` with the cloud-init instructions for your EC2 instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "your-instance" {
  ..
  user_data              = file("user_data/ebs-mount.sh")
  ..
}
```

where `user_data/ebs-mount.sh` has the next content (considering that EBS disk have xfs format):

```
#cloud-config
hostname: your-instance

runcmd:

- sudo mkdir /custom -p
- sudo echo '/dev/nvme1n1 /custom xfs defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
- sudo mount -a

output : { all : '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log' }
```

Comment: I had to format my disk, since it was an ext4. And used the mount command differently.


`sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1`
`sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /custom`

These commands would replace the command #2, #3 above in the answer.